# Low frame rate on LibGDX app that does nothing

Tags: android, libgdx, frame-rate

I'm quite new to LibGDX and don't have much experience with Java either, but trying to learn. I already made a simple game, but am struggling with the FPS; the game reaches 60 FPS on my Galaxy S5, but only 40 FPS on my Galaxy Tab S 10.5. The Desktop app also runs only 40 FPS on my laptop (Old-ish HP EliteBook with Win7, Core i7, 12GB RAM). I tried removing various things from the game but nothing seemed to improve the frame rate.

Then I created an "empty" LibGDX test project (with Libgdx Project Generator), called "test". It does NOTHING else but outputs the fps counter to Gdx.app.log, but still only reaches 40 FPS (delta time around 25 ms for every call).

Is it just that the LibGDX itself is too heavy for my laptop and Galaxy Tab S? Or am I doing something wrong? Or is there something wrong with my development environment? Which consists of

- Windows 7 Pro 64bit
- Android Studio 1.2.2
- JRE 1.8.0_45-b15 amd64
- Android SDK Tools 24.3.3, Platform-tools 22, Build-tools 22.0.1
- LibGDX Version 1.6.4

Libgdx Project Generator does complain that I have more recent version of Android build tools and API than recommended, and I also remember reading that Android Studio would not support Java versions above 1.7. Could those be the causing the performance issues?

Below the code of my test app (which runs 40 FPS on my laptop), it has only 2 classes written by me:

TestGame

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class TestGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        setScreen(new GameScreen());
    }
}
```

GameScreen

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    public GameScreen() {}

    @Override
    public void show() {}

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.app.log("FPS", (1/delta) + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

Here's the DesktopLauncher:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import [my package name].TestGame;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new TestGame(), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens to the frame rate if you add `Gdx.gl.glClear(0,0,0,0);` to the `render` method in your test case? And what value to you get if you change the log to `Gdx.app.log("FPS", Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());`? Also, can you share your code where you initialize the game (show your application config)?

Comment: What happens when you use the method  `Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()` instead of `1/delta`? I'm using this on my low-cost computer, and I'm hitting 59-60 FPS every time.

Comment: Gdx.gl.glClear only accepts one parameter so I tried Gdx.gl.glClear(0), which had no effect. Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond() also shows 39-41, and the real problem is not the counter anyway, I think it's working - the actual frame rate just is like that. My PC's display is so slow that it can't really be noticed, but on Galaxy Tab S it's very noticeable. I guess the device can only refresh screen on 1/60s intervals so 40fps causes annoying judder. 

By "code where you initialize the game" do you mean the DesktopLauncher? (Sorry I really am novice in this...) that is now added above.

Comment: You should always clear the backbuffer as the first thing you do in your render method: `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`. Also make sure to disable any ("smart") power saving options.

Comment: Also tried that (it's included in my actual game as it was in the tutorial I followed), but no effect on frame rate. Could power saving options also cause the frame rate drop on a laptop? As far as I can see all of them are disabled.